# Instancio: always getting "Unused selectors in generate(), set(), or supply()"

Tags: java, testing, instancio

I would like to generate customizable test data using instancio. This is my POJO:

```
@Data
public class MyPojo {
    private Integer id;
    private LocalDate modifiedAt;
    private String modifiedBy;
}
```

The test data are produced with this method:

```
public List<MyPojo> dummyData() {
        return Instancio.ofList(MyPojo.class)
            .size(100)
            .generate(field(MyPojo::getId), gen -> gen.ints().range(1,100))
            .generate(field(MyPojo::getModifiedAt), gen -> gen.temporal().localDate().past())
            .generate(set(MyPojo::getModifiedBy), "static value")
            .create();
    }
```

This leads always to the error *Unused selectors in generate(), set(), or supply()*
for every selector used in the example above.
One solution is to use `.lenient()` but after that, all my customizations are ignored.

The example from https://github.com/instancio/instancio-quickstart/blob/main/src/test/java/org/example/Instancio4CollectionsTest.java runs properly and I don't see any differences to my code.

How can I fix my problem ?

Comment: Assuming `generate(set(MyPojo::getModifiedBy), "static value")` is a copy/paste error and should be `set(field(MyPojo::getModifiedBy), "static value")` instead, the example looks good to me. If you provide a minimal reproducible sample via a [Github issue](https://www.github.com/instancio/instancio/issues) I can investigate further.

Comment: I've created an issue. The error only occures within the Vaadin/Spring Application, raw tests works properly. I've added a screenshot showing maybe important differences in the trace logs of org.instancio. See https://github.com/instancio/instancio/issues/637